# Why do I have two desktops for one user?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I'm using windows 10. When I open up the file explorer and click on the pinned desktop tab on the side, I see what's actually on my desktop. But when I browse to `C:\Users\mav\Desktop`, an empty folder pops up. There's only one user on the machine. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 offers the ability to remap the default folder [where your user folders are stored on the disk](https://www.dummies.com/computers/operating-systems/windows-10/how-to-change-the-location-of-user-folders-in-windows-10/). For instance, under the "Location" tab, you can change where the "Desktop" folder is physically located on the disk for the currently logged user, for example:

[image]

I would recommend moving out all files/folders from the old / new location before changing/applying it, and then adding them back again, especially if you have any form of folder or file sharing / syncing going on with that user (see One Drive below). I've seen some syncing issues arise with this feature otherwise.

Something else to look at: [Microsoft One Drive](https://support.office.com/onedrive) comes packed with Windows 10 and it might get configured automatically when you first create your user and configure your environment when it gets installed. You'll notice One Drive does come packed with a "Desktop" folder which can be used to sync your "Desktop" folder(s) for the current user.

This is one place to investigate. You can find more details on configuring and using One Drive [in this handy tutorial](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-get-started-onedrive-windows-10).